HTML built-in Dark mode
I'm building a website with HTML and I'd like to know whether there is a built-in option for dark mode and if so then, what it is.
I've already tried using CSS for it but my website has gotten so large now that it isn't feasible to do it for every part.

You can do a primitive "fake" dark mode by applying some CSS filters, inverting colors and doing some hue corrections - https://gist.github.com/jerrylususu/c517f091f3d733cf28e29e55b77b50d5 But the results are usually not all too good - "proper" dark mode often requires more nuanced modifications, than simply "flipping" colors into their opposite.

A good article that tells you about dark mode, and how to implement it, is: prefers-color-scheme: Hello darkness, my old friend.
